# Graph API: Adding Captions To User Generated Photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, instagram

I'm trying to get my application to post photos to a user's timeline using [the user generated picture feature of Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/). Unfortunately, while I can easily get the picture to the user's timeline, I haven't found any documented way to pass along a caption.

Instagram seems to have figured it out: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYsiX.png

Yet, if you go to the page of one of their posts, you'll notice that the caption isn't present in any of the Open Graph meta tags, so I'm guessing this is a value passed along with the POST.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please can you tell me, How you have implemented the User Generated photos in your app. Currently i am doing iOS app. I should use the upload a photo like yours (http://i.stack.imgur.com/TYsiX.png). Already i am using " og:image[0][url]='.$myurl.'&og:image[0][user_generated]=true " . But no luck. Please Can you help me in this?.

Comment: @sathiamoorthy you'd obviously would have to spend more time on the networking implementation, but at its simplest level all you need to do is     <code>NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]; [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/[youraction]?access_token=%token&%object=%objectaddress&image[0][url]=%imageurl&image[0][user_generated]=true&message=%message"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];<code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an optional message attribute that you can pass to the action:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-actions/

Under optional arguments.

It takes special approval when you submit your action for approval

Answer (score 0):

You should add "User Messages" Property in the followed image.
[image]
And then Give your caption in "message" tag.